# Order of operations in substitution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

If I have a (poorly written) expression such as $2\div2\times3$ I see the symbolic term $2\times3$ and wish to replace it $2(3)$ however the method of substitution involves use of parenthesis.

If I had:

$2x+1$

Under $x$ to $1+3$

This becomes

$2(1+3)+1$

If I take my expression,

$2\div2\times3$

I get $2\div(2(3))$

Now that $(2(3)$ is in the parenthesis instead of getting $3$, I actually get $1/3$, on top of this the order of operations has clearly changed, changing the original expression's meaning.

I understand that we can change expressions by substitution into new ones, but in this case it completely changes the meaning of the original expression. Is it incorrect to 'substitute' here as there is no real 'occurrence' of $2\times3$ in the same way as in an expression like $(2\times3)+1$ as this expression really can be written as $(2\div2)(3)$

Does a correct substitution from an expression $E$ taking a sub-expression $x$ to a sub-expression $y$ require preservation of the order of operations that were in $E$?

If I wished to substitute $2\times2$ into $3\div2(2)$ to yield $3\div2\times2$ would this be a valid substitution? If I ignore the parenthesis to try to change the expression without altering the order of operations?

Comment: Can you try rewriting your question more clearly? It's not clear to me what you want to find out.

Comment: "*poorly written expression*" is right... The punchline should be that poorly written expressions are....... *poorly written*.  If the expressions were *not* poorly written, it should have been clear what happens after substitution.  Do not write poorly written expressions in the first place and you will not have any trouble.

Comment: As for "*the order of operations has changed*"  No... it really hasn't.  Are you thinking it changed because "parentheses" appears first in "PEDMAS"?  But $2(3)$ doesn't fall under the "parentheses" category... That was meant more for things like $\sin(x)$ or for finishing having evaluated the addition first in something like $2(2+1)$.  What you refer to still falls under the "multiplication" part of PEDMAS, just that there happens to be an invisible implied multiplication sign as $2\times (3)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm doing $2\div2\times3$ left-to right but in $2\div(2(3))$ theres another parenthesis so $2(3)$ needs to be evaluated first as it's in a parenthesis. Perhaps it can be done the other way conventionally, it's more that when we actually re-write it $2\times3$ disappears in $(2\div2)(3)$

Answer (score 2):

> I have a expression such as $2\div2\times3$. I see the symbolic term
> $2\times3$ and wish to replace it $2(3)$

Impossible. To see why, it would help to imagine all of the implicit bracketing.

Effectively, you want to substitute the string "$(2(3))$" for an occurrence of the string "$(2\times 3)$" found within the string "$((2\div 2)\times 3)$". Do you see the problem?

Comment: The definition of substitution is to replace one 'occurrence' with another; would it be correct to say this is not a proper ''occurrence' of $2\times3$ more an it appears so.

Comment: @user1007028 That is correct.