# Are parenthesis required for subsitution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Do we need to use parenthesis to substitute into an expression, for example if I have an expression like $2\div4(3)$ I might wish to replace the $4(3)$ with $4\times3$ it is doable without parameters, so I simply replace one set of symbols with another, giving $2\div4\times3$, however if we simply replace one symbol with another it is misleading as there is no actual operation on the value $4\times3$ (there is a multiplication between ($2\div4$) and $3$) it is just that there appears a $\times$ between '$4$' and the $'3'$, is the parenthesis required to avoid this?

Comment: In my honest opinion, using $\div$ at all is terrible notation and should be avoided at all costs

Comment: The notation $2 \div 4(3)$ is strange and ambiguous.  I don't know what it's intended to mean.  You could write $(2 \div 4) 3$ if you mean first divide $2$ by $4$ and then multiply by $3$.

Comment: How is this different than your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544415/is-order-of-operations-in-substitution)?

Comment: Ignoring the issue with the $\div$ symbol, which again is poor notation and should not have been used and leads to confusion such as in this case... Yes, we know that... say for example... $3+4$ is equal to seven... and although those characters "3", "+", and "4" appear in that order in a different expression... such as $2\times 3 + 4$, no we may not simply replace "$3+4$" in "$2\times 3 + 4$" with seven

Comment: That is... again... because we are not simply replacing characters in strings with other characters in strings... but rather we are replacing *mathematical objects*.  There is not an object in $2\times 3 + 4$ which could have been described as being "$3+4$".  If you need to write excessive parentheses to see this, writing it as $(2\times 3)+4$, then so be it.

Comment: I guess to 'substitute' is to replace an expression by another, we could replace a set of symbols with another and these are different @JMoravitz Could we say that $4\times3$ is not a sub expression of $2\div4\times3$

Comment: I would say that it is not.  I would call it a sub*string* but not a sub*expression*.  Context is incredibly necessary.  You can not ignore what appears around it.

Comment: @user1007028: Please explain (in the body of the question) how this question differs from [your previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4544415/409). This will help people avoid giving responses you have already seen.

Comment: @JMoravitz Makes a lot of sense actually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Addition and multiplication have the nice property that $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$ and $(ab)c=a(bc)$ called [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). However both subtraction and division fail to have this property since in general $(a-b)-c \neq a-(b-c)$ and $(a/b)/c \neq a/(b/c)$. There is another property called [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) which addition and multiplication have which means $a+b=b+a$ and $ab=ba$ but again, subtraction and division fail to have this property.

To avoid this problem in higher math we just get rid of subtraction by adding negative numbers and division by multiplying reciprocals. So this means when I write $a-b$ I really mean $a+-b$ but it seems excessive to add the extra symbol all the time. The same happens for multiplication too where $a/b$ means $a(1/b)$ instead but again, we don't want all those extra symbols so we use the shorter version. In practice this is a very good way to avoid errors so it's worth thinking about things from this point of view.